# jQuery add class to dynamic content loaded by plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, dynamic, plugins

As stated in the title, I need to use **addClass** as well as a click function on content that is being dynamically loaded into the page a few seconds after page load via a plugin. I would also need it to work if the plugin/content is loaded via AJAX so it would need to continue checking for any '.my-link's

The click function I'm trying to use is..

```
$('.my-link').click(function(){
      var href= $(this).attr('

      $('body').fadeOut( 500, function(){
            window.location=href;

      })
      return false;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
 $( document ).delegate( ".my-link", "click", function() {
    // your code goes here
 });
```

Comment: and what would you suggest for the addClass

Comment: just after your element is loaded use addClass

Comment: it's loaded through a plugin so I have no control over it